# Why does this timer script not work as intended?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have modified this script: https://vincoding.com/weekly-repeating-countdown-timer-javascript/

That script displays a timer until a specific time on a specific day (0-6 = sunday through saturday), and once it reaches zero - it immediately starts counting down to that same day and time next week. There is a problem with it, however. When it reaches 0:00:00:00, instead of showing 6:23:59:59 on the next second, it shows 6:00:00:00. And THEN it shows 6:23:59:59. So, the day switches correctly, but the hour, minute and second are 1 second late.

Here is a live codepen of my modified version of the script:
https://codepen.io/RootB/pen/poePpOx

and the code itself:

```js
timerEndDay = "monday";
timerEndTime = {
  "hour": 18,
  "minute": 00,
  "second": 00
}
timerFrequency = "monthly"; //weekly, biweekly, monthly

var curday;
var secTime;
var ticker;

function getSeconds() {
  var nowDate = new Date();

  var dy = 0;
  switch (timerEndDay) {
    case "sunday":
      dy = 0;
      break;
    case "monday":
      dy = 1;
      break;
    case "tuesday":
      dy = 2;
      break;
    case "wednesday":
      dy = 3;
      break;
    case "thursday":
      dy = 4;
      break;
    case "friday":
      dy = 5;
      break;
    case "saturday":
      dy = 6;
      break;
  }

  var freq = 0;
  switch (timerFrequency) {
    case "weekly":
      freq = 7;
      break;
    case "biweekly":
      freq = 14;
      break;
    case "monthly":
      freq = 30;
      break;
  }

  var countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), timerEndTime.hour, timerEndTime.minute, timerEndTime.second);

  var curtime = nowDate.getTime(); //current time
  var atime = countertime.getTime(); //countdown time
  var diff = parseInt((atime - curtime) / 1000);
  if (diff > 0) {
    curday = dy - nowDate.getDay()
  } else {
    curday = dy - nowDate.getDay() - 1;
  } //after countdown time
  if (curday < 0) {
    curday += freq;
  } //already after countdown time, switch to next week
  if (diff <= 0) {
    diff += (86400 * freq)
  }
  startTimer(diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
  secTime = parseInt(secs);
  ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
  tick(); //initial count display
}

function tick() {
  var secs = secTime;
  if (secs > 0) {
    secTime--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(ticker);
    getSeconds(); //start over
  }

  var days = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
  secs %= 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs %= 3600;
  var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs %= 60;

  daysLeft = curday;
  hoursLeft = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours;
  minutesLeft = ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins;
  secondsLeft = ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs;

  document.getElementById("p2").innerText = "Time left: " + daysLeft + ":" + hoursLeft + ":" + minutesLeft + ":" + secondsLeft;

}


getSeconds();
```

```html
<p id="p2"></p>
```

This version just makes it easier to set the day and time on top of the script, and has an additional timer frequency option. You can set timerEndTime to any time, like 30 seconds in the future, and you will see the problem once it reaches zero. Both the original script and this one have the same problem, so it's not my modifications.

I have tried overwriting the hours, minutes and seconds to simply show "23:59:59" at this specific moment when it normally shows "00:00:00", and that is slightly better, but...of course, the timer is still late by 1 second, so it will then be stuck at "23:59:59" for an additional second. I can't figure out how to "push" the timer by one second.

Comment: Typo: `daysLeft = curday;` should be `daysLeft = days;`

Comment: I've tried that before but that seems to completely bug out the timer after about an hour or so. I'll try to test it out again just in case last time something else influenced it...

Comment: Your code doesn't ever decrement the days left in the counter.

Comment: Yeah but days is based on "secs"? And "secs"is assigned like this: first "diff" is set to 86400 * freq, giving the number of days in seconds. Then the function startTimer is ran with that number of seconds. Then in startTimer, "secTime" is set to this number of seconds. Finally, in tick(), "secs" is set to this number of seconds. And then the "days" variable is set to that number of seconds, but in days. So i have no idea where to adjust the code, that all seems fine to me, but i'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: I tested it overnight again, and, for a few hours, it correctly displayed 29:xx:xx:xx, meaning 29 days left, but then after a few hours, "days" reset to 0, showing 0:xx:xx:xx (hours, minutes, and seconds remained correct). I have no idea how to debug this...maybe i should just write my own script.

Comment: I was only addressing what happens when the timer reaches 0. It seems to have other problems with the day. When I use monthly frequency, it seems like `timerEndDay` has no effect.